# Is it possible to distribute an iphone app in a specific group of people?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ipa

I need to distribute an iphone app of mine in a group of 50 people that i know. I want them and only them to use it. Is it possible to distribute an iphone app outside AppStore? I know i could generate an .ipa for jailbroken phones , but the phones are not jailbroken. Is there a solution in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe basically there exists three different official [iPhone/iPad application distribution methods](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) :

**- App store**

With this method anyone with an iPhone can have access to the application. You can distribute an unlimited number of applications like this. Apple gets a 30% cut. Of course Apple must approve your applicaion.

**- Ad hoc**

You can distribute applications using ad hoc without going through the app store, but you are limited to a maximum of 100 devices. With this method you can distribute you application from a web site, email, etc.

**- Enterprise**

The method is for internal distribution in companies with more than 500 employees. Apple does not provide any more public detail that I could find on this method.

It doesn't sound like any of these methods meet your criteria unless you have fewer than 100 customers and don't plan to exceed that number. It sounds like from the question your customers are not internal to your company.

I would advise contacting Apple. They might be able to work out some kind of custom distribution deal.

Comment: Only thing to add is I believe ad-hoc and I know for sure that Enterprise profiles expire once a year so you will be required to update the app once a year if you choose one of those options.

Comment: I just need it for my college friends to inform them about some events. Ad hoc solution what exactly is this? can you give me some more information/

Comment: @donparalias..for ad-hoc distribution u need to get the device UDID of ur frnds...then add that device into ur portal account..

Comment: This is provided by apple? I need to have an iOS developers account for this?

Comment: @donparalias...i am sure YES

Comment: I know that apple lets 100 testers to every iOS developer license if thats what you mean

Comment: yes thats for normal account...once u have the enterprise edition,then u can distribute as many number of test apps over the air..

Comment: @donparalias...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

Comment: hahaha yes i know that but it costs 299$

Comment: but no thank you very much but that was not what i was looking for

Comment: +1, I am afraid there are no other ways other than those mentioned above.

Comment: You can get an Enterprise license with a smaller number of employees, all you need is a D&B number

Answer (score 0):

There is a very convenient way to do this with up to 100 people. Essentially, you add the UDID's of your people's devices to an AdHoc distribution profile through Apple's developer website.

Also, check out http://www.testflightapp.com for very convenient way to distribute such IPAs.

Comment: For this i need to have a developer's license?

Comment: I dont want to use my 100 user "tester accounts" that comes with my developers license if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an ad hoc distribution to up to 100 users. I don't remember how long the provisioning profiles last, but I'm thinking it's 90 days or something like that. You'll have to update the provisioning profile and distribute that to all your users every 90 days (or whatever it is).

If you distribute one version of the app to 50 people, then delete 25 of those people and try to add 75 more for the next version, even though you think you'll only have 100 users you actually have 125. The removed UDIDs still count against your 100-user limit. You can reset your 100 users once per year.

Comment: Thank you Craig yes i am very well aware of that , but i dont want to use my "tester accounts" for this purpose. i need those for serious application testing. This is only an application among friends

Answer (score 0):

Without a developer license and a valid provisioning profile, your app will not be able to be installed on any device (that isn't jailbroken). Once you have created a provisioning profile, it must be installed on all devices that wish to use the app. The exception to this is using an Enterprise code signing identity which does not require devices to be provisioned and is useful for internal distribution. In any case, you will need a developer account if you wish to do anything other than work on the simulator.